# How to compare lme models with different fixed variables?

Tags: statistics, statsmodels

If you have 2 linear mixed effect models with the same y variable and with the same dataset but with **different** fixed variables.

model 1: a * b
model 2: c * d

Can you compare them by using AIC? I am using statsmodels/Python and I know how to calculate AIC, just I could not find info about whether AIC is the right choice here.

Thank you!